# SwiftGen integration with SPM for Localization

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, swiftgen

I'm trying to integrate SwiftGen Plugin using SPM within a project that has multiple packages for localization. So I picked the package where I need SwiftGen and did the following:

1. I've performed all the steps highlighted at [here](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGenPlugin).
2. Configured .yml file like this:

```
input_dir: Sources/Example/Resources
output_dir: Sources/Example/Generated

strings:
  inputs:
    - en.lproj
  outputs:
    - templateName: structured-swift5
      output: Strings.generated.swift
```

3. When I try to run I get **Plug-in ended with non-zero exit code: 1)** with error:
   **Error: You don’t have permission to save the file “Strings.generated.swift” in the folder “Generated”.
   **

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to change the output folder but nothing, same thing.. I can't find any resource on the web regarding on how to integrate SwiftGen for localization within an existing SPM package.

Answer (score 0):

You should use it as command

```
swift package --allow-writing-to-package-directory generate-code-for-resources
```